# ¿Cómo puedo alinear dos imágenes horizontalmente con CSS?

Tags: css, html5

Las imágenes no se alinean es como si una imagen tuviera un bloque por así decirlo mas grande que la otra y lo máximo que se alinea es como se muestra en la imagen.

Agrego código `HTML` y `CSS`

[image: Foto de la pagina]

```css
.logo {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nombre {
  display: inline-block;
}

.logo img:first-child {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <img src="Imagenes/logo.png" width="70" ; alt="icono" ; title="GastroBlog" ; />
</div>
<div class="nombre">
  <img src="Imagenes/nombre.png" width="200" ; alt="name" ; title="GastroBlog" ; />
</div>
```

Comment: Debes tener algún conflicto en el `CSS`. Le agregué un snippet a tu pregunta y las imágenes se alinean tal como sugieres que deberían estar. Intenté también con algunas imágenes de https://picsum.photos/ y funciona perfecto. Ah no ser que tu contenedor sea menor de 270px de ancho.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda , fue un error con el tamaño de las imágenes pero ya lo solucione.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es poner las 2 imágenes en un contenedor con el atributo `display: flex;`. Te dejo un ejemplo:

```css
.logo{
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/05/Facebook_Logo_%282019%29.png/800px-Facebook_Logo_%282019%29.png" width="70"; alt="icono"; title="GastroBlog";/>
  <img src="https://logodownload.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/facebook-logo-15.png" width="200"; alt="name"; title="GastroBlog";/>
</div>
```

Comment: Ya lo acabo de hacer y queda igual solo que ahora el logo esta arriba

Comment: Holaa, muchas gracias por tu sugerencia resulta que era un error por el tamaño de las imágenes aunque estaba en png la imagen no era toda solo del logo tenia espacios .

Answer (score 1):

¡Hola! bueno, yo te recomendaría que pusieras una caja contenedor primero. No sé si vas a ocupar todo el viewport, pero para que sean alineadas se añadería un Flexbox. sería así:

```
<div class= "container">
 <div class="logo">
      <img src="Imagenes/logo.png" alt="icono"; title="GastroBlog";/>
    </div>
    <div class="nombre" >
      <img src="Imagenes/nombre.png" alt="name"; title="GastroBlog";/>
    </div>
</div>


   .container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 250px; (este es un ejemplo)
      display:flex;
    }
```

Yo te aconsejaría usar flexbox para mejor acomodo, pero las cajas de nombre y logo tienen que tener el mismo tamaño.

```
.logo, .nombre {
width: 250px; 
heigth: 250px; 
}
```

Para que las imagenes no queden tan estrechas ni pixeleadas, te recomiendo usar este código en css

```
.logo, .nombre img{
width: 100%;
heigth; 100%;

}
```

solamente con tu margin juega que tan pegadas quieres ambas imágenes, pero estoy segura que con lo que te acabo de escribir te va a quedar centrado. No es recomendado agregar un tamaño directo a la imagen. Muchos saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda